# Trying to read JSON (using GSON) into an Object which has another object as a field.

Tags: java, json, rest, gson

so I am using Google's GSON library for making sense of JSON strings. I have it working where the Object I am saving is `User` with a statement like :

```
User user = gson.fromJson(string, User.class),
```

but I can't seem to understand how save a string with a "nested object." Here's the statement that is giving me errors:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Request request = gson.fromJson(requestInput, Request.class);
```

where the `requestInput` is

```
String requestInput = "{key: \"123\", requestType: \"POST\", requestModelType: \"USER\","
            + " obj: {username: \"alex\", email: \"email@gmail.com\", password:\"pass\"}}";
```

My `User` class looks like this:

```
public class User implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -24243416292823789L;

    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private List<Circle> circles;
    private List<Notification> notifications;
    ...
```

And my `Request` looks like this:

```
public class Request {

    private String key;
    private String requestType;
    private String requestModelType;
    private User user; 
    ...
```

Finally, I am getting the following error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
...
```

Any help on this or suggestion on a better design is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

@SerializedName("obj")
private User user;

So that GSON knows that the "obj" in your JSON should be mapped to the user field.

The actual error you showed is a little different, I'm not sure how you are getting that particular error--it means that you have something declared as a String in the Java but an Object in the JSON.

Comment: This has actually helped! I would not have thought to look up an annotation for a long time!